# Empty request when send object to 'show' method in controller

Tags: laravel, request

I am trying to send an object to the `show` method and I am getting it with no attributes.

**index.blade.php**

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.specialities.show', [$speciality])}} "> {{$speciality->display_name}}</a>
```

**web.php**

```
 Route::resource('admin/specialities', 'SpecialtyController', 
   ['names'=> ['index' => 'admin.specialities',                                                                                                                                           
               'show'  => 'admin.specialities.show',]]);
```

**SpecialtyController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Backend\Specialty;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SpecialtyController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('specialities.specialities')
            ->with(['specialities' => Specialty::all()]);
    }


    public function show(Specialty $specialty) {
        dd($specialty); //<- always null atributes
        return view('specialities.show', compact('specialty'));
    }
}
```

**Specialty.php**

```
namespace App\Models\Backend;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Specialty extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the route key for the model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
}
```

Any ideas what may be wrong or where to check?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `id` on the route:

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.specialities.show', $speciality->id)}} "> {{$speciality->display_name}}</a>
```

In your controller you can find the especific model:

```
public function show(id) 
{
    $speciality = Specialty::FindOrFail($id);
    return view('specialities.show', compact('speciality'));
}
```

Change your index method to:

```
public index()
{
    $specialities = Specialty::all();
    return view('specialities.specialities', compact('specialities'));
}
```

**Note**

You should be careful when declaring variables, you have a model named **Specialty** but your variable representing that model is `$speciality`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use slug

Comment: i don't think that is the problem. Try doing what i writed in the answer